# What is the bit encryption that is enough for today's web apps

Tags: security, authentication, ssl

What is the highest encryption bit that is currently usable on the latest browsers. I have seen providers issuing 128 and 256 bit certificates. Are higher bit certificates usable in browsers? Are they publicly available ? Also is 128 / 256 bit still unbreakabale based on today's computing power ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen providers issuing 128 and 256 bit certificates.

No, you haven't. Not recently anyway. The key sizes in the certificates tend to be 1024, 2048 or above. (It's not recommended to go below 2048 nowadays.)

What makes the encryption key size (128 or 256 bits) isn't the size of the key in the certificate. The key in the certificate is used for asymmetric cryptographic, which takes place during the SSL/TLS handshake to perform an authenticated exchange of *symmetric* key (negotiated for this SSL/TLS session).

This symmetric key is used for encryption, and its size can indeed be 128 or 256 bits, typically. The size is dictated by the cipher suite that is negotiated (e.g. something based on AES-128 or AES-256). This key size is independent of the certificate's key size.

Comment: I was looking at godaddy and on their site I could see they were only advertising the cipher key of 128 and 256. Nowhere was the certificate key size mentioned. Which certificate providers should I consider ?

Comment: As I said, 128/256 encryption will depend on how the server and the client are configured (the latter is beyond your control). There's a lot of blurry information from some CAs (incl GoDaddy), mostly because they want to provide reassuring words for commercial purposes, at the expense of technical accuracy. If you hover over the 256-bit encryption label [here](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=9039), it says "*With the right combination of browser/server [...]*. EV certs mandate 2048 bits for the cert key at least, but most non-EV certs will do that too, GoDaddy included.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, appreciate your comments.

Comment: I was talking about the 'Compare Plans' tabs, btw. The cert key side will depend on the CSR.

Comment: Any ideas on what is the maximum bits key avalaible for the cert ? I mean what is the best I can get above 2048?

Comment: @murtaza52 I deal with Godaddy, and they insist on at least 2048 bits, RSA, for certificates they sign.